# Spyder console not executing commands

Tags: python, spyder

I am trying to execute some commands in Spyder Console but it isn't working [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGHGN.jpg)

Comment: shift + Enter :S ?

Comment: Thank you very much @dtlam26 it works :)
It used to work simply with Enter though

Comment: okay,  then pls close the post and accept my answer :D

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Sometimes execution can fail with `Enter`, but it usually works. Are you able to execute other commands with `Enter` after the first one you execute with `Shift+Enter`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally for Ipython, execution should be launched by Shift+Enter instead of Enter. Have a great day in Stackoverflow ;)